# How to print the result of a line generator?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following code:

```
valuelinePath = svg.append("path")
    .data([data])
    .attr("class", "line2")
    .attr("d", valueLine)
    .attr("transform", "translate(42" + ", 70" + ")");

var newvalueLine = d3.line()
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.years);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d[cityName]);
      });

 valuelinePath
    .data([data])
    .attr("class", "line2")
    .attr("d", newvalueLine)
    .attr("transform", "translate(42" + ", 70" + ")")
    .style("display", null);
```

I assume newvalueline is string generated by the string generator but no, when I try to debug the value of newvalueline, the debugger tells me that it is a function

```
newvalueLine
ƒ t(t){var a,c,s,f=t.length,l=!1;for(null==i&&(u=o(s=ee())),a=0;a<=f;++a)!(a<f&&r(c=t[a],a,t))===l&&((l=!l)?u.lineStart():u.lineEnd()),l&&u.point(+n(c,a,t),+e(c,a,t));if(s)return u=null,s+""||null}
```

but when I access the attr("d") of the valuelinePath I just assigned it to, it is able to return me the correct string representation of that path

```
valuelinePath.attr("d")
"M-3285.4586214143906,388.2L-3285.458621411788,307.8L-3285.4586214091855,124.79999999999995L-3285.4586214065826,97.19999999999999L-3285.45862140398,12.599999999999966L-3285.4586214013775,243L-3285.4586213987745,43.19999999999999L-3285.458621396172,14.400000000000034"
```

So how do I get the string representation of the newvalueLine for debugging purposes, without having to assign it to the valuelinePath attribute and retrieve it again? Why is it a function not a string?

things I read upon https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-paths-and-d3js
https://bl.ocks.org/d3indepth/e312c205b6b07757551bffafb265589b

I am assuming the line generator returns a path string like in the above example? No?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the returned value of a line generator, which is a *string*, all you need to do is to pass a data array to it. For instance:

```js
const data = d3.range(10).map(d => [d, d]);
const lineGenerator = d3.line();
console.log(lineGenerator(data))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

And this pretty much answers the question in the title. However, we must also explain your confusion.

The part in your code that got you confused was this one:

```
.attr("d", newvalueLine)
```

After reading your question it seems to me that you though that `newvalueLine` was already a string, being passed to the `d` attribute of the path. The confusion becomes clear here: *"I assume newvalueline is string generated by the string generator but no, when I try to debug the value of newvalueline, the debugger tells me that it is a function"*. However, as you can clearly see, `newvalueLine` is a **function**.

What's happening here is something very well documented in D3 API. For several methods, like [`.selection.attr`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_attr), you can pass both a constant or a function as the `value` attribute. If the `value` is a function, the function is called and its **returned value** is used. As the API says:

> selection.attr(name[, value]) <>
>
> [...] if the value is a function, it is evaluated for each selected element [...] The function’s return value is then used to set each element’s attribute.

*"But where are the arguments passed to `newvalueLine`?"*, you might ask. Again, the API explains:

> [...] if the value is a function, it is evaluated for each selected element, in order, being passed the current datum (d), the current index (i), and the current group (nodes), with this as the current DOM element (nodes[i]).

Therefore, this:

```
.attr("d", newvalueLine)
```

Is the same of this:

```
.attr("d", function(datum){
    return newvalueLine(datum);
});
```

We can easily demonstrate this in the following snippet, which doesn't use D3 at all. Here there is a function named `callback`, which gets the passed argument and multiplies it by 2. A function `foo` accepts two arguments to set a given value, if the second argument is a function it calls it.

Pay attention to how we use `callback` in `foo` to set the value of `value`.

First, just using the function's name, without any argument:

```js
function callback(datum) {
  return datum * 2;
};

function foo(firstParameter, secondParameter) {
  if (typeof secondParameter === "function") return secondParameter(firstParameter);
};

//Look here:
const value = foo(2, callback);

console.log(value)
```

Now, explicitly passing the argument:

```js
function callback(datum) {
  return datum * 2;
};

function foo(firstParameter, secondParameter) {
  if (typeof secondParameter === "function") return secondParameter(firstParameter);
};

//Compare the snippet above with this:
const value = foo(2, function(d) {
  return callback(d)
});

console.log(value)
```

As you can see, the arguments are automatically passed to the callback.

Answer (score 0):

It is created as a function, because it can't actually create the path until you send the data to it:

```
valuelinePath
    .data([data])
    .attr("class", "line2")
    .attr("d", newvalueLine) // This is when the path is actually created
```

It's a part of the way that D3 works, it is declarative, think about it as a set of rules that you define, and then you throw data at it to render a chart.

In this way, if the data is different, you just pass new data to it and the generator function will then generate the path. `generator function` is key to this - that's what the documentation is referring to.